# PHP to post to different user dependent on form name

Tags: php, html

Trying to work out the best way to get the `PHP` below to post to a different user email address dependent on the form name it is coming from.

Eg. this form is `name="engineering-australia"` and I have others with different names. I want this one to go to user1@domain.com and an other to go to user2@domain.com and so on.

My question is, what would be the best way to do this, I don't want to use javascript- I was thinking some kind of `if` statement? But wouldn't the form name need to be pulled in somehow?

Also worth mentioning the forms are identical apart from the form name, I didn't want to just create a different `PHP` script for each form.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-contact" name="engineering-australia">
    <fieldset>
        <input id="form-name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" />
        <input id="form-email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email" />
    </fieldset>
    <textarea id="form-msg" name="message" rows="10" placeholder="Your Message" ></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button button-small" value="Send Message" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

define('kOptional', true);
define('kMandatory', false);

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
ini_set('track_errors', true);

function DoStripSlashes($fieldValue)  { 
// temporary fix for PHP6 compatibility - magic quotes deprecated in PHP6
 if ( function_exists( 'get_magic_quotes_gpc' ) && get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) { 
  if (is_array($fieldValue) ) { 
   return array_map('DoStripSlashes', $fieldValue); 
  } else { 
   return trim(stripslashes($fieldValue)); 
  } 
 } else { 
  return $fieldValue; 
 } 
}

function FilterCChars($theString) {
 return preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F]/', '', $theString);
}

function CheckEmail($email, $optional) {
 if ( (strlen($email) == 0) && ($optional === kOptional) ) {
  return true;
  } elseif ( preg_match("/^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$/i", $email) == 1 ) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
 $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
 $clientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$FTGname = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['name'] );
$FTGemail = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['email'] );
$FTGmessage = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['message'] );
$FTGsubmit = DoStripSlashes( $_POST['submit'] );

$validationFailed = false;

# Fields Validations

if (!CheckEmail($FTGemail, kMandatory)) {
 $FTGErrorMessage['email'] = 'ERROR MESSAGE';
 $validationFailed = true;
}

# Redirect user to error message

if ($validationFailed === true) {

 header("Location: index.php?success=2");

}

if ( $validationFailed === false ) {

 # Email to Form Owner

 $emailSubject = FilterCChars("Website Enquiry");

 $emailBody = chunk_split( base64_encode( "<html>\n"
  . "<head>\n"
  . "<title></title>\n"
  . "</head>\n"
  . "<body>\n"
  . "Name : $FTGname<br />\n"
  . "Email : $FTGemail<br />\n"
  . "Message : " . nl2br( $FTGmessage ) . "\n"
  . "</body>\n"
  . "</html>" ) )
  . "\n";
  $emailTo = 'User <user1@domain.com>';

  $emailFrom = FilterCChars("$FTGemail");

  $emailHeader = "From: $emailFrom\n"
   . "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
   . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n"
   . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"
   . "\n";

  mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $emailBody, $emailHeader);

# Redirect user to success message

header("Location: index.php?success=1");

}

?>
```

Comment: What is the question, having problems? Errors?

Comment: do you create your forms dynamically?

Comment: @user3980820 Nope, I'm pretty new to this

Comment: well,they gived you the answer you're looking for but i think that you should create your forms dynamically, wich will save you time.

Comment: @user3980820 Thanks! I'll look into it as I don't know much about it. Cheers

Comment: you can make a php webpage `forms.php` And then include it.The code will be : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c981aad8a522a994bd1b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to get the form name in PHP.  Try using a hidden input in each form:

```
<input name="form" type="hidden" value="engineering-australia" />
```

Then check `$_POST['form']` in PHP.

```
switch($_POST['form']) {
    case 'engineering-australia':
        $email = 'user1@domain.com';
        break;
    case 'something-else':
        $email = 'user2@domain.com';
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<form class="form-contact" name="engineering-australia">
    <fieldset>
```

To:

```
<form class="form-contact">
    <input type="hidden" name="post-to" value="engineering-australia" />
    <fieldset>
```

Now you can check who you want to send the email to by simply requesting `$_POST['post-to']` on the submit action page.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I considered a hidden field but didn't think it was the cleanest way, I guess it is! :) Cheers